# What does TOP's DATA column mean?

Tags: linux, memory, top

I'm trying to figure out the meanings of all the different classifications of memory such as VIRT, RES, SHR, AND DATA.  While I generally understand the first 3, I have no idea what the DATA column means other than it's official definition as DATA = Data+Stack size (kb).  How does this relate to the other 3 classifications of memory?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://techtalk.intersec.com/2013/07/memory-part-2-understanding-process-memory/:

> That field is computed by the kernel as a difference between two variables: total_vm which is the same as VIRT and shared_vm. shared_vm is somehow similar to SHR in that it shares the definition of the shareable memory, but instead of only accounting the resident part, it contains the sum of all addressed file-backed memory. Moreover, the count is done at the mapping level, not the page one, thus shared_vm does not have the same subtlety as SHR for the modified private file-backed memory. As a consequence shared_vm is the sum of the quadrants 2, 3 and 4. This means that the difference between total_vm and shared_vm is exactly the content of quadrant 1.
>
> The DATA column contains the amount of reserved private anonymous memory. By definition, the private anonymous memory is the memory that is specific to the program and that holds its data. It can only be shared by forking in a copy-on-write fashion. It includes (but is not limited to) the stacks and the heap2. This column does not contain any piece of information about how much memory is actually used by the program, it just tells us that the program reserved some amount of memory, however that memory may be left untouched for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

From the man pages:

```
 s: DATA  --  Data+Stack size (kb)
 The amount of physical memory devoted to other than executable code, also known  as
 the ’data resident set’ size or DRS.
```

In other words memory used to store variable data of for your programs (not executable programs)

Say like and Array in memory is variable data.

Also `stack size` is like the words say, the size of your stack that the system is using to execute the particular program. The stack is where the system stores the traceback of functions that your program/process is calling. Keep in mind that this metric says the stack size and not the stack itself.

More on the other memory columns that you mentioned [here](http://mugurel.sumanariu.ro/linux/the-difference-among-virt-res-and-shr-in-top-output/)

Answer (score 0):

From the man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

```
The amount of private memory **reserved** by a process.  It is also
known as the Data Resident Set or DRS.  Such memory may not yet
be mapped to physical memory (RES) but will always be included in
the virtual memory (VIRT) amount.
```